# Как добавить кнопку Backward в Activity?

Tags: android, activity

Как добавить кнопку возврата на предыдущий активити, взамен использования системной кнопки?
Пример на рисунке ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

Comment: взамен системной,хмм , только если создать button и внутри onClick замутить startActivity, либо onBackPressed()

Comment: не сколько взамен, сколько чтобы не нажимать системный backward, а пользоваться этой новой кнопокй

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*не сколько взамен, сколько чтобы не нажимать системный backward,а пользоваться этой новой кнопокой*

Вообще по Вашему рисунку видно следующее:
Toolbar - это удачная замена старому доброму ActionBar.

```
*toolbar.xml*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/triple_height_toolbar"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Для работы с toolbar:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class AndroidToolbarExample extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                onBackPressed();// возврат на предыдущий activity
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

P.s. toolbar работает везде одинаково, начиная с android 2+

Comment: Получилось воспользоваться кодом после некоторых изменений: 1. В Android Studio 2 проект создавался на Basic Activity. 2. Потом правка следующая -         
                //onBackPressed();// возврат на предыдущий activity
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Нажата кнопка Backward в Toolbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           так как в MainActivity - это выход из программы

Answer (score -1):

Не совсем понятно что именно ты хочешь сделать
если заменить иконку делай так:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_drawable_icon);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawable);
```

Если хочешь по нажатию на предыдущую активити делай так:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```